# Complement of $\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\geq f(x)\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, limsup-and-liminf

In the context of the question:

"What is the complement of $M:=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)\geq f(x)\right\}$?"

I ran into the following problem.

---

We see that

\begin{align*}
&M=\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{j=n}^{\infty}\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid f_j(x)-f(x)>\frac{1}{m}\right\}\cup\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{j=n}^{\infty}\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid f(x)-f_j(x)<\frac{1}{m}\right\}.
\end{align*}

So by law of De Morgan it follows directly

\begin{align*}
&M^c=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)< f(x)\right\}\\
&=\left(\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{j=n}^{\infty}\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid f_j(x)-f(x)>\frac{1}{m}\right\}\cup\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{j=n}^{\infty}\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid f(x)-f_j(x)<\frac{1}{m}\right\}\right)^c\\
&=\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{j=n}^{\infty}\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid f_j(x)-f(x)\leq\frac{1}{m}\right\}\cap\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{j=n}^{\infty}\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid f(x)-f_j(x)\geq\frac{1}{m}\right\}.
\end{align*}

If we consider the example $f:\mathbb{R}\to\{0\}$ and $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\{-1,1\}$ with $f_n(x)=(-1)^n$, then clearly $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=-1<0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. However, in this case
$$
\bigcap\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{j=n}^{\infty}\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid f_j(x)-f(x)\leq\frac{1}{m}\right\}=\emptyset.
$$

And this makes no sense. Where is my mistake?

Comment: Why '$\{\liminf f_n<f\}$' is not a valid answer? Is there some requirement on the final form of our set?

Comment: @Snoop, yes it is a valid answer. But it doesn't solve my problem...